# Google Cloud Folders

Tags: directory

We recently moved our local server to the Cloud. My question is when creating folders for projects; are we able to create a **"project templates"** that contains all folders needed. My challenge has been, are we able to duplicate these folders? I don't see an option to duplicate or copy Folder. I would love to hear your recommendations on this.